# Checking Cell values for US states

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to calculate freight costs based on delivery state as starting location. Multiple states will use the same formula. The part of my code that I am concerned with is below

```
Dim STATE As String
Dim PLANT As String
Dim MILES As Integer

STATE = Range("STATE").Value
PLANT = Range("PLANT").Value
MILES = Range("MILES").Value

If STATE = "AL" Then

    If PLANT = ("PLANT") Then

          Result = (((MILES - XXX) * XXX) + XXX)

              Range("FREIGHT") = Result
```

The STATE entry cell is controlled by a list box, and I need to check for multiple states. ie, AL, AZ, AR etc. What would be the best way to do this without writing `If STATE = XX` over and over again?

Comment: Select  Case comes to mind...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Select...Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx).

It helps you, for example, check multiple options of a varible, without having to mess with nested If statements.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do, but I think you mean that multiple cases would "generate" the same fomula.

Here is a simple example using Select...Case :

```
Select Case STATE
     ' Put here all the states that is in the first group.
     Case "AL", "BL", "CL","DL"
          ' Code for the first group.
     Case "EL","FL","GL","HL"
          ' Code for the second group.
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply- while that does look like it would alleviate some typing, it looks like I would still be comparing all 50 states. To be clear, I have 4 specific scenarios that would change my math formula, depending on states. So for example- a state from group A gets one formula, a state from group B gets another, group c , and group d.... I see what you're going but I'm not going to need a new formula for every state.

Comment: @Chad2157 I've edited my answer. I hope I understood what you meant.